# How to cross compile 64 bit Python with MXE

Tags: python, mxe

I have a project cross-compiled from Linux to Windows using MXE. In the process of moving from 32-bit to 64-bit I'm having a problem at runtime on Py_DECREF. Full details here:

[Python XDECREF failing on 64bit mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213665/python-xdecref-failing-on-64bit-mingw)

I am thinking that there may be some issue with an odd interaction between the mingw exe and the DLL file and I've got stuck on that route. As an alternative plan I am trying to cross-compile python too, to produce a .a file I can link with rather than the DLL.

I am stuck with trying to find the correct set of ./configure and make args, currently:

```
CONFIG_SITE=config.site ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/opt/mxe.master/usr//x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-shared --disable-ipv6
make clean HOSTPYTHON=./hostpython BLDSHARED="x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc- -shared" CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-w64-mingw32- CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes EXTRA_CFLAGS="-Wno-strict-aliasing"
```

but this is failing as MS_WINDOWS isn't getting #defined, which must mean I've missed something on how to properly include the PC/pyconfig.h (and anything else from that directory)